# The useState set method not rendring the specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update my `TaskDetail` (at Right Side) component with new `card` data but when I change the value of card from `handleCardClick` callback it does not reflect the change to that specific component. If you look at attached gif you will see that `useEffect`  is getting the updated values of `card` and the `page` variable in the same call back showing updated value on view.

[image]

Here is the minimum code that depict my problem.

```
 const [selectedCard, setSelectCard] = useState(null);
  const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState(null);
  // Page Updater
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);


  const handleCardClick = (e, card, columnId) => {
    
    setSelectedColumn(columnId);
    setSelectCard(card);
    setPage(page + 1);
    
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of movies
    console.log(selectedCard);
    console.log(selectedColumn);
    
}, [selectedCard]);


return (
    <Container>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
        {boardData.map((list) => (
          <List key={list.title} column={list} handleAddTask={handleAddTask} handleCardClick={handleCardClick} />
        ))}
      </DragDropContext>
      <p>{page}</p>
      <> {(page !== 0) && <TaskDetail card={selectedCard} columnId={selectedColumn} />}</>

    </Container>
  );
```

This is the most relevant to my question [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) but I did't find the solution from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try 2 things:

1. Check the `TaskDetail` code to see if it has state management of it's own. If it does, you need to make sure it triggers re-render when the relevant props change (trigger it by calling setState inside the component for example)
2. Add a unique `key` to the `TaskDetail` component to force it to re-render when the key changes.
   For example:

```
<TaskDetail key={selectedCard.id} card={selectedCard} columnId={selectedColumn} />
```

Comment: Assigning the `key` to component solve the issue. Thanks